# Competing risk survival random forest with large data

Tags: r, random-forest, large-data, survival

I have a data set with 500,000 observations with events and a competing risk as well as a time-to-event variable (**survival analysis**).

I want to run a **survival random forest**.

The R-package `randomForestSRC` is great for it, however, it is impossible to use more than 100,000 rows due to memory limitation (100'000 uses 40GB of RAM) even though I limit my number of predictors to 15 to 20.

I have a hard time finding a solution. Does anyone have a recommendation?

I looked at `h2o` and `spark mllib`, both of which do not support **survival random forests**.

Ideally I am looking for a somewhat R-based solution but I am happy to explore anything else if anyone knows a way to use large data + competing risk random forest.

Comment: Do you absolutely need 500k records to fit a model? Have you tried subsetting a random smaller sample, fit a model and monitor some metric? By adding number of observations you can see how parameters change. Perhaps, at some point, the parameters and their confidence intervals won't really change?

Comment: That's a good idea. I will look into the performance when adding records to see when it levels out. I am still interested in a solution in a big-data environment though.

Comment: (Voting to close as basically requesting a package search.) Not sure if this handles whatever (non-specified) competing risk issues you are dealing but perhaps helpful?
 ... https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3944969/

Comment: Thank you. Cox models do run easily on big-data, but random forest is more challenging it seems. Yes, I am looking for advice on how to use Spark + survival forest or another solution for big data. Should this question not be on Stackoverflow? I can delete it if that is the case.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4289620/  combined with https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4151379/ might fit the requirements

Comment: I think it might be useful to leave it up even though it is not really a coding question. If the other close voters do not think it should be migrated (which was my vote), you might try posting on CrossValidated.com, a sister site for SO.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the memory profile for an RF-SRC data set is n x p x 8 on a 64-bit machine.  With n=500,000 and p=20, RAM usage is approximately 80MB.  This is not large.

You also need to consider the size of the forest, $nativeArray.  With the default nodesize = 3, you will have n / 3 = 166,667 terminal nodes.  Assuming symmetric trees for convenience, the total number of interanal/external nodes will approximately be 2 * n / 3 = 333,333.   With the default ntree = 1000, and assuming no factors, $nativeArray will be of dimensions [2 * n / 3 * ntree] x [5].  A simple example will show you why we have [5] columns in the $nativeArray to tag the split parameter, and split value.  Memory usage for the forest will be thus be  2 * n / 3 * ntree * 5 * 8 = 1.67GB.

So now we are getting into some serious memory usage.

Next consider the ensembles.  You haven't said how many events you have in your competing risk data set, but let's assume there are two for simplicity.

The big arrays here are the cause-specific hazard function (CSH) and the cause-specific cumulative incidence function (CIF).  These are both of dimension [n] x [time.interest] x [2].  In a worst case scenario, if all your times are distinct, and there are no censored events, time.interest = n.  So each of these outputs is n * n * 2 * 8 bytes.  This will blow up most machines.  It's time.interest that is your enemy.  In big-n situations, you need to constrain the time.interest vector to a subset of the actual event times. This can be controlled with the parameter ntime.

From the documentation:

ntime:  Integer value used for survival families to constrain ensemble calculations to a grid of time values of no more than ntime time points.  Alternatively if a vector of values of length greater than one is supplied, it is assumed these are the time points to be used to constrain the calculations (note that the constrained time points used will be the observed event times closest to the user supplied time points).  If no value is specified, the default action is to use all observed event times.

My suggestion would be to start with a very small value of ntime, just to test whether the data set can be analyzed in its entirety without issue.  Then increase it gradually and observe your RAM usage.  Note that if you have missing data, then RAM usage will be much larger.  Also note that I did not mention other arrays such as the terminal node statistics that also lead to heavy RAM usage.  I only considered the ensembles, but the reality is that each terminal node will contain arrays of dimension [time.interest] x 2 for the node specific estimator of the CSH and CIF that is used in creating the forest ensemble.

In the future, we will be implementing a Big Data option that will suppress ensembles and optimize the memory profile of the package to better accommodate big-n scenarios.  In the meantime, you will have to be diligent in using the existing options like ntree, nodesize, and ntime to reduce your RAM usage.